How can I build an application for java 1.8 using Eclipse?
How can I prevent a "module" error when running a Java 1.8 application using Eclipse,
My first PC application using Eclipse. I hadn't paid attention to the level of Java I'm using, but discovered it was 17. My app works fine when run under Eclipse. It also works fine when exported to a .jar file.
I want to create a .exe version. Using Launch4J I got an error saying I was using java 61, but Launch4J only supports up to 52. So, changing the Eclipse Project Settings, I set the java version to 1.8:

When trying to run the application under eclipse, I got the following error:

After some research, I learned that "module" was added with Java 1.9. Out of curiosity, changed Eclipse Project Settings, specifying version 1.9, and the application works fine.
But (of course) I get a similar error from Launch4J (using java 53; only supports up to java 52)
What should I do in Eclipse so I can build the program with Java 1.8?
If there is a solution involving launch4J, or if there's an alternative to launch4j, please let me know.
Thank you.

Note that you can use jlink on current versions of Java to build an executable just using standard tools

Launch4j (launch4j-3.50-win32.exe), with JDK 17 example ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78939031/generated-exe-not-working-standalone-program-written-in-javafx-scenebuilder/78948594#78948594 )

I found the module-info.java file and deleted it. That solved the problem.
